# Are there any properties of a function that are valid when a function is defined on an open interval but not when it's defined on R?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

It is customary to make theorems about functions being defined on open or closed intervals. For example, [Froda's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froda%27s_theorem) states that

> Let f be a real-valued monotone function defined on an interval I. Then the set of discontinuities of the first kind is at most countable.

even though this theorem is also valid when a function is defined on the $(-\infty,\infty)$. Are there any examples of theorems for which this is not true? That is, are there any theorems valid when the function is defined on an open interval $(a,b)$, $a,b\in\Bbb R$, but not when it's defined on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Any open interval is homoemorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so at least for continuos functions the answer is no. Differences arise for closed intervals or may arise if the volume of the domain of defnition plays a role, or ....

Comment: Are you taking the position that $\Bbb R$ is not an open interval? It is!

Comment: Here is an example: any uniformly continuous function defined on a bounded interval must be bounded. This is not true for functions defined on $\Bbb{R}$, for example $f(x)=x$ is not bounded over $\Bbb{R}$, although it is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since open intervals $(a,b)$ are homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ (both as topological spaces and linearly ordered spaces), every property dealing with continuity and order must hold in both cases, or none of them. Local properties (for example being locally Lipschitz, or locally bounded) behave in the same manner as well. So we need to look for global properties which deal with metric.

The following properties of a function $f$ are true whenever the domain is an open interval, but they need not to be true when the domain is $\Bbb{R}$:

1. if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then it is bounded
2. if $f$ is bounded and continuous, then it is Lebesgue integrable
3. if $f$ is continuous and bounded, then its Riemann integral always converges